# SelectedIndexChanged to open a new form

Tags: asp.net

I have a web page with a datagridview where a user should be able to click on the selectindexchanged (in this case a "Select" button) show the results of what they have selected in a label on the second page and also redirect them to that page. Here is the code I have for the vb.net:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        TimeDateLabel.Text = String.Format("Today is {0:F}", DateTime.Now)
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub whosoncallButton_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles whosoncallButton.Click
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim connectionString As String = "Initial Catalog=mdr;Data Source=xxxxx;uid=xxxxx;password=xxxxx"
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "getoncall"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subschedule", TextBox1.Text)
        Try
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
            con.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write("Error:" & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Protected Sub clearButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles clearButton.Click
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        GridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow
        Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?msg=" + row.Cells(1).Text)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I have also added a line to my aspx page for the event handler.

I have debugged this but no matter what I've tried so far, the SelectIndexChanged event isn't firing. Can someone assist me on this please?

Thank you

Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CommandName property of the ButtonField must be set to 'Select' to trigger the SelectedIndexChanged event.

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Select"  CommandName="Select" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your ASPX GridView it is impossible to tell for sure why this isn't working but I would guess you aren't generating your select button correctly. Do you have this property set in your GridView?

```
autogenerateselectbutton="True"
```

---

Based on what you posted in the comments below you can change your ASPX code to either of the following to have it work:

Using your current ButtonField ([Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname.aspx)):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center"
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

With Auto-Generation ([Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogenerateselectbutton.aspx)):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center"
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
    AutoGenerateSelectButton="True">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: ThechrisKent, this is all I have on my gridview: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
             <Columns>
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Select" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

Comment: @Doug Ancil I have updated my answer with a couple of solutions that should work for you.